# Meteor app deployed to Azure not showing

Tags: git, azure, deployment, meteor

There's a handy tutorial here:

http://help.nitrous.io/azure-sites/

That runs through setting up a meteor app and deploying to Azure. I did get a `Deployment successful.` when deploying this app. However, my app appears with only `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` on the page.

I'm not much of a server configuration person. Small words please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting error after pushing to Windows Azure: You do not have permission to view this directory or page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461338/getting-error-after-pushing-to-windows-azure-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/7ce6d174-d8be-4d50-9635-943dc3343359/new-site-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page), you might need to set a default document.

Answer (score 0):

In your meteor bundle open this file "..\bundle\programs\server\packages\webapp.js" and search for "process.env.PORT".

```js
var localPort = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 0;
```

alter this line into:

```js
var localPort = process.env.PORT || 0;
```

This is needed so your meteor project can accept a named socket as soon as it runs in node on azure.