# How to fix "Azure deployment with VS Code gives 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.'"

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, .net-core, visual-studio-code

Hey StackOverflow geniuses! Long time reader, first time writer here :)
I'm trying to deploy a simple .Net Core MVC app to Azure, but I'm getting the good ol' "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" when I browse the site.

I created a basic mvc app with the `dotnet new mvc` (no other changes) and deployed it with the VS Code Azure App Service extension. It runs locally and everything seems fine during the deployment process, but I still get that error.
Now I've tried creating the same app in Visual Studio 2017 using the mvc template. And when I deploy that it seems to work fine.

I'd like to use VS Code exclusively. If you guys have any insights on what it's doing differently and how I might be able to fix it, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to deploy a simple .Net Core MVC app to Azure

How did you do that?

If you do a `dotnet publish` from your VS code terminal or from any command line it will create a `publish` folder under your `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\` you need to right click on this folder in your VS code and click the "Deploy to WebApp..." after this it works fine for me. I assume you were getting the error because you deployed a different folder.

If this does not help you can turn on the diagnostics logs, like they do it here: [Azure website message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

Comment: Uhh, I think I'm an idiot, but I'm going to blame it on the Azure extension. Did what you said and it worked perfectly.. Thank you!!!