# You do not have permission to view this directory or page in AzureDevops

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-devops

[My release  was successfully completed and generating the webapp URL,but when i click on that url it haven't displayed my web page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhsIZ.png) I am getting this type of error,I am deploying the sample html static web page using the azure devops,It was successfully deployed but i have not get the webpage showing an error like:"You do not have permission to view this directory or page".I am try to deploy the same with the python also but getting the same error in this case also.
url:http://html1213111webapps.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: You need to show screencaps of what you are doing, steps to reproduce. This is a poorly worded question and i have no idea how to answer it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure website message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

Comment: Flagged it as duplicate.
Basically checkout this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page/48854367).

Comment: I Tried in all different ways which are recommended by the people,but i still facing the same error? I got all files in kudu console but havn't resolve thta error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error description, it is not very clear about what went wrong here. So you can refer to the link provided by Jonas in the comment for troubleshooting.

Many startup errors don't produce useful information in the Application Event Log. You need to check whether your deployed web app files are available or not through [KUDU Console](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/04/01/get-azure-website-deployment-logs-from-kudu/).

You can open `xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net`. This should redirect you to KUDU interface where you can see few tabs.Or open **Advanced Tools** in the **Development Tools** area, select the **Go**→ button, the Kudu console opens in a new browser tab or window . Using the navigation bar at the top of the page, open Debug console and select CMD . Then go to site-> wwwroot,that should contains all your files.

Also, make sure that your index.html is added to wwwroot , you can check this from **Site wwwroot** tab.

In addition , you can enable [diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) for apps in Azure App Service to check the complete error details and root cause.

For other detailed troubleshooting , please refer to the similar question link in the comment.