# How to deploy Asp.net web forms website to Azure Web App service using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Want to deploy Asp.net web forms website to Azure Web App service using Azure DevOps. All files from project are being copied to the artifact. When deploy that artifact to Azure Web App service, getting following issue:

> `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

Comment: What is the authentication for the web app supposed to be?  What is the authentication set to in the app service?

Comment: Hi the error is ambiguous and can be caused by multiple reason. You can follow below answer to troubleshoot the issue

Answer (score 1):

`You do not have permission to view this directory or page`. This error can be caused by multiple reasons.

It could be some code files were not included in the artifact deployed to Azure Web App service. Or the artifact is deployed to the wrong place instead of `wwwroot/`.

So you can log into the kudu server(open `<your_web_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`) to check if the artifact is in the right place and all the files are uploaded.

It also could be there was no default page in your Azure website. You can add a default page and set it as default page in appsetting on the Azure portal.

It also could be the application permission issue. Try re-adding the delegate permission.

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page) For more information.