# After deploying the react application on azure getting error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I deployed the react application on azure with windows environment. After accessing the website getting the following error
"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I added the web.config file inside the root still getting the same error.

web.config file code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to see what is happening in the logs, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page

Comment: Tomasz Kaniewski's suggestion is good, but that issues mentioned in that post is `.net `web app.  I recommand to deploy your web app by git, or check log to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

When encountering an error message, first we can view the log. There are many ways to specifically it. You can view the `Application Event Logs` in the `Diagnose and solve problems` in the web app.

**Troubleshooting steps:**

1. First of all, confirm what code file changes were made before the error message occurred. This may be the cause of the exception.
2. Check the running log of the existing program. It is recommended to check relevant documents or [blog articles](https://willi.am/blog/2015/07/24/debugging-nodejs-azure-web-apps/) for learning.
3. If you ensure that the above steps are normal, it is recommended that after ensuring that the program runs normally locally, the code is [continuously deployed through git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment), and the release status is checked in Action.

(Because of your current error message, I probably took a look, it should be a deployment failure)