# azure webapp You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure, vnet

Hi I have a simple web app created with terraform, configured with vnet regional integration:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-indigo" {
  name                = "app-${var.environment}-${var.app_name}"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-plan.id
  

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
  } 

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "app-indigo-swift" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.app-app.id
  subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet["integration"].id
}
```

no matter how I try to access the web app, from internal network or an application gateway, I get the following

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

and this is the default web-app, no code deployed yet, I'd really appreciate any help here

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure website message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

Comment: I read it before posting, unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could happen there is a lack of `Web.config` file in your `wwwroot` folder. If you leave out the `site_config`, Terraform will invoke the Azure API to create a default website. This error will disappear.

So you can use code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-indigo" {
      name                = "app-${var.environment}-${var.app_name}"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app-plan.id         
}
```

Alternatively, you could deploy your website including web content. For example, you could create [an ASP.NET Framework web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnet-framework).

[The example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html#example-usage) provisions a Windows App Service. Other examples of the azurerm_app_service resource can be found in the [./examples/app-service directory within the Github Repository](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/tree/master/examples/app-service).

Comment: Thanks Nancy, that's a great tip, i thought the hostingstart.html is always created ! :)

donno if you can answer, I have one more question please, i need to use site_config to restric/allow ip_addresses and i did add GatewaySubnet (the vpn P2S) to the allowed, however, i can't access the web app, even after allowing it

Comment: It's a default page when web apps deployed in Azure, see the [old document](https://www.vembu.com/blog/how-to-use-azure-web-apps/). If you only allow P2S VPN client to access your web app, you should add the address pool(CIDR block) from Point-to-site configuration instead of GatewaySubnet in your virtual network gateway.