# Release from Azure DevOps to Azure App Service: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I saw a lot of posts about this issue. I want to create my pipeline from Azure DevOps to Azure App Service.

In DevOps I created my pipeline like:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: |
     **/PowerBIDashboard.csproj
     **/PowerBIDashboard.Tests.csproj

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: test

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-o publish_output'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

[image]

In the **Release** I deploy the artifact to the App Service. In **Kudu** of the App Service, I can see all files.

[image]

I deleted the App Service and re-deploy with the same result. Then I try to deploy directly from Visual Studio but I have another error.

[image]

Then, I check the logs in Kudu and I found in the eventlog.xml those errors:

```
<Events>
    <Event>
        <System>
            <Provider Name="ZipFS"/>
            <EventID>0</EventID>
            <Level>1</Level>
            <Task>0</Task>
            <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-10T16:24:34Z"/>
            <EventRecordID>-1126954890</EventRecordID>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>RD281878C97A29</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>Failed to open siteversion.txt. ZipFS setup failed. Error: 0x80070003</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <System>
            <Provider Name="ZipFS"/>
            <EventID>0</EventID>
            <Level>1</Level>
            <Task>0</Task>
            <Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
            <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-10T16:24:34Z"/>
            <EventRecordID>-1126954875</EventRecordID>
            <Channel>Application</Channel>
            <Computer>RD281878C97A29</Computer>
            <Security/>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data>Failed to copy zip from remote source.</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
</Events>
```

Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you ever fix this? I'm getting the same "Failed to open siteversion.txt. ZipFS setup failed. Error"

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The deployment from DevOps is most likely using a feature called Run From Package which runs the app from the zip file and puts the D:/home/site/wwwroot directory in read only mode. Based on the application type DevOps will attempt to pick the best deployment method. Run from package is recommended to avoid issues with locked file and to ensure the files that are running.

If you want DevOps to use another method you'll want to use ZipDeploy without Run From Package or Msdeploy. I haven't worked extensively with YAML in DevOps but I *think* you'll want to do something like this under the input depending on whether you choose zipDeploy or msDeploy.

deploymentMethod: zipDeploy/msDeploy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#prerequisites-for-the-task

[Run from package reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package)

[Dev Ops deployment type Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#deployment-methods)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have created a lot of pipelines and releases for projects following the scripts/procedure I posted and it was always working. I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Does your app have this app setting set to 1? WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE

Answer (score 0):

> For Azure App Service: “You do not have permission to view this directory or page”

From the screenshot, the files have been upload to the `site/wwwroot` path successfully.

You need to check the `Path mappings` of your Application Settings. Then in the `Virtual applications and directories` section, You need to change your `Physical path` to `site/wwwroot/appname`.

You could get more detailed steps in [the Blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-angular-application-on-azure-web-service-960e441bb13d).

If above doesnot work out. You can do below steps to show more error messages and troubleshoot the issue.

- Go to Your Web App in Azure> App Service logs >turn on Detailed Error Messages.
- In the Web Config file add `<customErrors mode="Off" />` under <system.web> tag, add `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>`  under <system.webServer> tag. And update the web.config file to your azure web app.

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page) for details.

> For the error in Visual Studio

You could refer to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/530948/azure-function-app-publish-fails-with-error-findin.html)

> Delete the App Setting "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" and it will let you redeploy.