# Web app not accesible after deploying to azure web app using azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have one asp.net sample application. I want to deploy this web application to the Azure web app, I used azure DevOps to build and release the pipeline.

I successfully completed the build and release but when I try to access the web app though the azure web app URL it reflects `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

How to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit `https://{yourwebsitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net` to check if your app files are deployed to `site/wwwroot` foler in Kudu server.

If your app files are deployed to folder `site/wwwroot/appname`. You need to check the `Path mappings` of your  Application Settings. Then in the `Virtual applications and directories` section, You need to change your `Physical path` to "site/wwwroot/appname". You can find more details in [this blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-angular-application-on-azure-web-service-960e441bb13d).

If above doesnot work out. You can do below steps to show more error messages and troubleshoot the issue.

- Go to Your Web App in Azure> App Service logs >turn on Detailed Error Messages.
- In the Web Config file add `<customErrors mode="Off" />` under <system.web> tag, add `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>`  under <system.webServer> tag. And update the web.config file to your azure web app.

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page) for details.