# NextJS and Azure - "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: azure, next.js

I've tried multiple walk throughs and YouTube videos, but I'm still missing something. I'm using Azure DevOps to build and Azure App Service to deploy. Those steps at least work to get my code deployed, I can see everything in /site/wwwroot from the Kudu DebugConsole.

[image]

I've tried creating a `server.js` file to set the port correctly:
https://github.com/willemliu/fd-design-system-test/blob/master/server.js

and I've included a web.config in the root to point to this server.js file:
https://github.com/MRCollective/nextjs-server-azuresiteextension/blob/master/Next.js/files/web.config

But no matter what I try, I keep seeing this permissions error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**SOLUTION!**

The problem was with my `web.config`. I swapped it out to this one and now everything works.
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config

Answer (score 0):

Majority of the times you may run into this issue due to incorrect virtual path -> physical path mapping. Please check to see if the virtual path mapping is done properly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

Similar question was answered here. please take a look and hope it helps.
[Azure website message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/azure-website-message-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

[image: Path Mapping]