# Azure App Service Authentication with OpenID Connect

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect

I am quiet a newbie to Azure. This is first time using it. I have a simple web api published to Azure App Service. I want to enable the OAuth authentication on that api. Here is the steps I have taken:

1. Published .Net Web API to App Service which can access successfully from Postman
2. From the App Registration, registered an app (e.g. App1)
3. Created a secret for App1 and Finished Expose the API with scopes
4. Added API Permissions
5. Then in the App Service (web api), setup Authentication with OpenID Connect provider point to App1

From the postman getting token  successful. When I tried calling API from Postman with received Token, I am getting error message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Is that the steps I have taken were wrong> or missed something?

Comment: For what all scopes did you acquire the token?

Comment: Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853599/how-to-debug-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page)

Comment: Kindly review and checkout [this](https://jsandersrocksblog.github.io/2021/09/07/preview-auth0-with-azure-app-services) step-step instructions (with screenshot) for enabling OpenID connect.