# Azure web apps: “You do not have permission to view this directory or page” error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy my nodejs application on azure and I got this error :

```
“You do not have permission to view this directory or page”
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) from Azure web site. To be sure Itried again but with the hello wold example given in the tutorial. However, when I deploy the zip, I got a successful deployment but when I try to access to my web site I get the same error.

I searched on internet about this error and I tried to follow the response from the following links [link1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/issues/9), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452336/you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page-error-in-azure) but I still get the error.

Do you have an idea please ?

I would be very thnakful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the documentation, if you get the issue after deploying the ZIP it means that there is an issue with sample App.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#download-the-sample

Make sure you follow the process accurately.

***Also did it run locally?***

Comment: This is exactly the one I followed and it works locally.

Comment: OK.  A common mistake people normally make is on the zip.  


**Make sure you're still in the root directory of the sample project. Create a ZIP archive of everything in your project**