# How to display a page in Azure Apps Service?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I am trying the sample code below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=javascript%2Cazure-powershell

I was able to move locally.
(Start URL: http: // localhost: 3000)
We are deploying the code to Azure Apps Service as a Zip file.
However, even if I access the site URL, it cannot be operated.
(Start URL: https: // {azure apps service} .azurewebsites.net)

I'm wondering if I should set Web.Config, but I don't know what to write.
If you know what to set in WebConfig with the above code, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.
Also, if there is a solution other than this, I would appreciate it if you could tell me that as well.

Comment: What is the error you are getting while accessing the URL ?

Comment: The error is "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Comment: Even if you specify the start file (./bin/www) of package.json in web.config, the code of the file will appear as pre tag as it is
Is this another problem?
What should I do if I don't want to display the code as pre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have followed the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/blobs/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=javascript,azure-powershell) which you have provided and it is working fine for me.
- I am able to upload images and check them in storage account.
  [image]
  [image]

> "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

- The root reason can be there is no default page in your Azure website.
- when you deploy the zip file via the azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI, make sure that you see the files being unzipped on the /wwwroot level.
- If the files show up under /wwwroot/your-app-folder/ you may get this permission issue.
- You could directly view the page with  url.

```cs
https://{siteanme}.azurewebsites.net/views/yourpage.html
```

**Add**  the  [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents)  in the project root folder and set it as default page in appsetting on the Azure portal and  **save**  the setting.

> The default document is the web page that is displayed at the root URL for a website.

[image]

- Navigate to   `KUDU`  url:  `https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`  and go to  `site\wwwroot`  to check if the files are contained within a directory.
- If you find any files missing , re-deploy the app.

  ***OR***
- Just for checking Temporarily, drag the local files directly to the  `d:home\site\wwwroot`  directory and try again.
- For debugging purposes you can turn on the Azure detailed messaging.
- Login to Azure > App Services  >  `Your Web App`  > App Service logs , then turn on  `Detailed Error Messages`  or turn on all of the logging options.
- Add the below in your  `Web Config`  file,
- add  `<customErrors mode="Off" />`  BEFORE system.web closing tag,  `</system.web>`. Similarly, add  `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>`  BEFORE  `</system.webServer>`.Upload the  `Web Config`  to Azure.

This  will show the error messages in detail , from there you can figure out the exact issue.

Please refere [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51490190) for more details.

Comment: @ HarshithaVeeramalla-MT - 
Thank you for your teaching.
The file was unzipped directly under wwwroot.
I have one question.
Do I need to build a new default page?
Or is there a specified default page in the sample?
If so, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Comment: @stkhr - Check if your Application has any default document , In Portal=>Your Application=>Advanced Tools=>Go=>Debug Cosole=>cmd=>site=>wwwroot. If you dont find any create one and check once.

Comment: Try to access url like - > https://{siteanme}.azurewebsites.net/views/yourpage.html

Comment: @ HarshithaVeeramalla-MT - Thank you for your teaching.
After reviewing the settings, I found that the file specification in the handler of web.config was incorrect and could not be seen.
Also, I was able to deepen my understanding of how to write the default page.
The check mark has already been pressed.
thank you.